# Hazelcast: How to create secure communication in Open Source?

Tags: hazelcast

We are ready to buy Open Source code. We want to implemented secure communication between two hazelcast or across all hazelcast which are on same network.

Please let's know how it possible,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.com. Please ask your question clearly stating the actual problem you are facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question was already answered in github (https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/8370). Hazelcast Opensource does not have transport layer security builtin. This is an enterprise feature but it certainly is possible to build it yourself (keyword `NodeExtension`).

For more details, see the linked github issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TLS between nodes but that requires an enterprise license http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-dev/manual/html-single/index.html#tlsssl

Answer (score 0):

The full security stack is provided as an enterprise benefit from Hazelcast. It ties in to LDAP/Kerberos and enforces RBAC access.

See: https://hazelcast.com/products/security-suite/